# match the values with the correct timestamp

Tags: timestamp

I've got a df in python which contains only 30 values with their timestamp, while they should be 96 (1 day, 15 minute timestep). So I want to keep the correct values with their timestamps and add zeros to the missing values. A generic example with 2 values would be the following:

Initial_df=[value1      timestamp1
value3      timestamp3]

then I create a complete timestamp column with 96 timestamps, how can I fit the correct values in the new order like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['value1', 'value3'],
               'timestamps': ['01-06-2023 00:00:00', '01-06-2023 00:30:00']})
```

and the new df would be:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['value1', '0', value3','0'...'0],
               'timestamps': ['01-06-2023 00:00:00', '01-06-2023 00:15:00','01-06-2023 00:30:00',....'01-06-2023 23:45:00']})
```

I hope the question is clear

many thanks!